# Define column selection order in pdf

Tags: pdf, itemize, two-column, description

I am trying to build a CV. Now I've noticed that the following seems to cause problems for automatic processing. Namely, the dates are not read correctly. When I select text in the pdf, I also get a wrong selection order; of course I want to select all the date before the rest of the item. How can I resolve this?

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc,array}
\newlength\descriptionwidthi
\settowidth\descriptionwidthi{\sffamily\bfseries 11/2012}
\newlength\descriptionsepi
\setlength\descriptionsepi{1ex}
\setlist[1]{
    labelwidth=\descriptionwidthi,
    labelsep=\descriptionsepi, 
    leftmargin=!, 
    parsep=.5ex,
    align=left,
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\range}[2]{\smash{\parbox[t]{\descriptionwidthi}{#1\\\llap{–\,}#2}}}
\begin{document}
    \section{John Doe}
    \begin{description}[]
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Some degree\\Activities:
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Something else\\Activities:
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Just for demonstration\\Bla bla bla
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well you would have to tag the pdf to define a reading order. But that isn't trivial in your example as neither scrartcl nor enumitem is currently compatible with the tagging code, and your use of parbox would need some special code too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I aleady read a bit about tagging and your package, but I guess it's all still quite experimental and lacking some introduction guide, right? Anyway, I am not confined to scrartcl and enumitem.

Answer (score 3):

As a proof of concept that tagging can help (this requires a current LaTeX. The interfaces for the lists are not finished and are bound to change!!):

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III,pdfversion=2.0} %or some other pdfversion
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\newlength\descriptionwidthi
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\settowidth\descriptionwidthi{\sffamily\bfseries 11/2012}}

\newcommand{\range}[2]{\smash{\tagstop
        \parbox[t]{\descriptionwidthi}{\sffamily\bfseries#1\\\llap{–\,}#2}}}
\begin{document}
    \section{John Doe}
    \begin{description}[label-width=\descriptionwidthi,
                        leftmargin= \descriptionwidthi+1ex,
                        label-sep=1ex,
                        ]
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Some degree\\Activities:
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Something else\\Activities:
        \item[\range{01/2011}{12/2015}] Just for demonstration\\Bla bla bla
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems not to work on TeX Live 2023 (because `\tagstop` is not known). What version do I need?

Comment: you need a current version of the tagpdf package.

Comment: Very nice proof of concept. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to inspect the pdf using ngpdf.com. It seems that your version strips the dates completely? At least, with phase-II and compiled with lualatex, I get the selection order I want and the correct text in ngpdf. Even with scrartcl or enumitem. Is there any harm in that?

Comment: ngpdf looks fine for me, but I'm on the newest development code currently (which will be released next week). But with ngpdf I would use pdf 2.0 `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III,pdfversion=2.0}`. With phase-II you will get only basic paragraph tagging and for example not list.